# Airflow marking long running tasks as Failed

Tags: python, airflow

We have a few long running tasks (100 hours+) in a few DAGs. The tasks internally call an http endpoint to kick off a process, and then poll the status + sleep for 30 sec in a loop. After about 40 hours or so, Airflow marks the job as failed, but there is no indication in the log as to why - last item printed for the task run was a  "Sleeping for 30 sec" statement". The triggered http process is also up and running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Issue solved - our Openshift pods were restarted due to a deployment which caused the workers,scheduler and webserver to exit. Thanks all for the input

Comment: How did you resolve it? I'm having a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141944/how-to-safely-restart-airflow-and-kill-a-long-running-task/63144913

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to wait until a status change, use sensors with rescheduling(maybe with a larger poll wait time). Your approach might be blocking workers and somehow if the worker lost its communication with the scheduler. Those tasks will get marked as zombies and it might get killed.

Comment: True and I agree we may have to change the approach, but I don't think it answers my question in this case. Also noteworthy that the task gets marked as failed, but the on_kill method defined for the task does not get called.

Comment: Check if the worker configuration caused the process of this task to get killed for some reason. it could be memory or any other.