# How to safely restart Airflow and kill a long-running task?

Tags: celery, spark-streaming, databricks, airflow

I have Airflow is running in Kubernetes using the CeleryExecutor. Airflow submits and monitors Spark jobs using the [DatabricksOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/databricks_operator.html).

My streaming Spark jobs have a very long runtime (they run forever unless they fail or are cancelled). When pods for Airflow worker are killed while a streaming job is running, the following happens:

1. Associated task becomes a zombie (running state, but no process with heartbeat)
2. Task is marked as failed when Airflow reaps zombies
3. Spark streaming job continues to run

**How can I force the worker to kill my Spark job before it shuts down?**

I've tried killing the Celery worker with a TERM signal, but apparently that causes Celery to stop accepting new tasks and wait for current tasks to finish ([docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#process-signals)).

Comment: Before you post, summarize the problem and provide details and example for that to describe what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more clear about the issue. If you are saying that the spark cluster finishes the jobs as expected and not calling the on_kill function, it's expected behavior. As per the docs on kill function is for cleaning up after task get killed.

```
def on_kill(self) -> None:
    """
    Override this method to cleanup subprocesses when a task instance
    gets killed. Any use of the threading, subprocess or multiprocessing
    module within an operator needs to be cleaned up or it will leave
    ghost processes behind.
    """
```

In your case when you manually kill the job it is doing what it has to do.

Now if you want to have a clean_up even after successful completion of the job, override post_execute function.
As per the docs. The post execute is

```
def post_execute(self, context: Any, result: Any = None):
    """
    This hook is triggered right after self.execute() is called.
    It is passed the execution context and any results returned by the
    operator.
    """
```

Comment: The spark job is still running. Airflow worker is being restarted, which creates a zombie process. Airflow reaps the local zombie process, but it doesn't cancel the still-running spark job.

Comment: I updated the question. Let me know if it's clearer now.

Comment: So you are launching a streaming job with an operator that expects a batch job. Batch jobs are expected to get completed sometime in the future. In your case, you are somehow launching a streaming job and the worker waits forever to see its completion and finally, it becomes a zombie. One option is to create a custom Databricks operator and just submit the job(remove the polling part ). Else just use a bash or python operator to submit the streaming job.